# How to make a group field as hyperlink in SPGridView

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spgridview

How to make a group field as hyperlink in SPGridView.
I have following code to add grouping for my gridview but it's not a hyperlink.

```
gridView.AllowGrouping = true;
gridView.EnableViewState = false;
gridView.GroupField = "Product";
gridView.GroupFieldDisplayName = string.Empty;
gridView.AllowGroupCollapse = true;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code in your `SPGridView` Design, you need to add '`HyperLink`' in your `<ItemTemplate>` as bellow

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkProduct" Text="Product" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("/SiteUrl/Product.aspx?ID={0}", Eval("ID")) %>' Visible="false" ></asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: It won't group the gridview.